# Why is my MacBook stalling occasionally since being upgraded with an SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I upgraded my 6 year old MacBook Core Duo with a 120GB SanDisk Extreme SSD. The results are pretty incredible considering the age of the computer.

The only problem I'm having are intermittent stalls. It's happened during tasks like using a simple text editor, to browsing, to watching videos, to just sitting idle. All of a sudden the cursor changes to the dreaded beachball and the system becomes completely unresponsive, except for being able to move the cursor.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you replace the internal hard disk with the SSD and its your only storage? Is the SSD the same capacity as the hard disk it replaced? Have you checked to see how much space is left on the SSD? OSX will have real problems with a HDD or SSD if it doesn't have enough room. If the SSD is close to full that might be a piece or all of this problem.

Comment: agree with @Richard especially regarding space concerns, if the SSD is full or close to it. Another thing to bear in mind is that SSDs have a fairly significant failure rate (atleast when compared with a mechanical) and from experience I have found that this can be a symptom of a dying SSD - essentially the writes fail and never finish because the block they are writing to is bad or damaged. you can probably find more info from the manufacturer about this, see if they have any known issues.

Comment: @Richard I replaced the stock 80GB HDD with a 120GB SSD. One thing I forgot to mention is that I did not perform a clean install on the SSD but rather used CCC or SuperDuper! (can't remember which) to copy the system from the HDD to the SSD. The SSD has enough free space on it.

Comment: So how much free space is on the 120GB SSD?

Comment: 18.5 GB at the moment.

Comment: 1/6 of the drive may not be enough for OSX to be happy temp writing files. I did an optical drive swap as well when I went to my 128gb SSD so I could keep everything on the 1tb HDD that replaced the optical drive. I was having the same issue and freeing up space on the SSD and putting it on the HDD helped alot!
15in - MBP E2011, 128SSD,1tbHDD, 16GB RAM

Comment: Here's what I'd do to test things out: If you still have the drive you took out, buy a cheap firewire enclosure for it, connect it to your computer and start up from it. If the stalling goes away then it sounds like there might be something wrong with the SSD.